# Which Ports need to be accessible on a Domain Controller for Clients to logon? continued

Tags: networking, active-directory, firewall, port, domain-controller

With reference to one of the questions asked "Which Ports need to be accessible on a Domain Controller for Clients to logon?" I have a aligned issue being faced. Please see the following ports which are opened for client computers before as reference.

`TCP: 53 88 135 139 389 80 445 464 636 3268 3269 1024 to 65535`

`UDP: 88 123 137 138 500 4500 464 389`

As we opened these ports, the issue we facing is DNS lookup from client does not work. Eg. we restricted Domain controller only allowed above ports. Then do nslookup from client computer, we cannot get result for some website address like: `www.bing.com`, `www.google.com`, `www.badiu.com` …etc. that means cannot resolve external web addresses.

Let me know if you have other questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Active Directory through a Firewall](http://serverfault.com/questions/45611/using-active-directory-through-a-firewall)

Comment: Sorcha is correct, udp 53 needs to be added. Dns typically uses udp and while some documentation states that dns will try to use tcp 53 if udp 53 is not available, Microsoft's products behave unpredictably as always

Comment: Please see the following ports which are opened for client computers before as reference. 

tcp  53 88 135 139 389 80 445 464 636 3268 3269 1024 to 65535
udp  53 88 123 137 138 500 4500 464 389

Answer (score 1):

> Please see the following ports which are opened for client computers
>   before as reference. tcp: 53 88 135 139 389 80 445 464 636 3268 3269
>   1024 to 65535 udp: 88 123 137 138 500 4500 464 389

You haven't open the port UDP 53 which is the port for the DNS requests from your client to your DNS server.

**EDIT1 :**

- Can you lookup a site (www.google.com) directly from your DC ?
- Can you lookup the name of a local machine for example from your client ?

If you have a 'yes' to these two questions, maybe your problem is from the DNS redirection on your DC.
If you have a 'no' your problem is from the opened ports on your DC.

Comment: Please see the following ports which are opened for client computers before as reference. 

tcp  53 88 135 139 389 80 445 464 636 3268 3269 1024 to 65535
udp  53 88 123 137 138 500 4500 464 389

Comment: see EDIT 1 on the answer